# Javafx updating tableview on object change

Tags: java, uitableview, javafx, tableview, observablecollection

I'm having some trouble updating a tableview in my java class.

```
package gameStats.controllers;

import gameStats.Main;
import gameStats.model.Team;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainController implements Initializable {

    private Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    @FXML
    private Label timerText;
    @FXML
    private Button startTimerButton, stopTimerButton, resetTimerButton, addTeamButton, addPointButton, removePointButton, newTimeButton;
    @FXML
    private TextField teamNameTextfield;
    @FXML
    private TableView teamView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Team, SimpleStringProperty> nameCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Team, SimpleIntegerProperty> pointCol;

    private ObservableList<Team> obsTeamList;

    private int min;
    private int startTimeSec, startTimeMin;
    private Parent borderPane;
    public BorderPane timeBorderPane;
    private boolean isRunning;

    public void startTimer() {
        if(isRunning == false) {
            if (!(startTimeMin < 0)) {
                KeyFrame keyframe = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                        startTimeSec--;
                        boolean isSecondsZero = startTimeSec == 0;
                        boolean timeToChangeBackground = startTimeSec == 0 && startTimeMin == 0;

                        if (isSecondsZero) {
                            startTimeMin--;
                            startTimeSec = 60;
                        }
                        if (timeToChangeBackground) {
                            timeline.stop();
                            startTimeMin = 0;
                            startTimeSec = 0;
                            timerText.setTextFill(Color.RED);

                        }

                        timerText.setText(String.format("%d min, %02d sec", startTimeMin, startTimeSec));

                    }
                });
                timerText.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                startTimeSec = 60; // Change to 60!
                startTimeMin = min - 1;
                timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
                timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyframe);
                timeline.playFromStart();
                isRunning = true;
            } else {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "You have not entered a time!");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        }else {
            timeline.play();
        }

    }

    public void setTimer() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("newTimeDialog.fxml"));
            Parent newTimeBorderPane = (BorderPane) loader.load();
            borderPane = newTimeBorderPane;
            Scene scene = new Scene(newTimeBorderPane);
            Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.showAndWait();
            if (!primaryStage.isShowing()) {
                min = NewTimeController.getMin();
                timerText.setText(min + "min, " + 00 + "sec");
            } else {

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void stopTimer() {

        timeline.pause();
    }

    public void resetTimer() {
        timeline.stop();
        startTimeSec = 60;
        startTimeMin = min-1;
        timerText.setText(String.format("%d min, %02d sec", startTimeMin, startTimeSec));
    }

    public void createTeam(){

        SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(teamNameTextfield.getText());
        SimpleIntegerProperty startPoint = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        if(!(obsTeamList.size() == 0)){
            for (Team t : obsTeamList) {
                if (!t.getName().equals(name)) {
                    obsTeamList.add(new Team(name, startPoint));
                    teamView.getItems().setAll(obsTeamList);
                }else {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Holdet eksistere allerede!");
                    alert.showAndWait();
                }
            }
        }else{
            obsTeamList.add(new Team(name, startPoint));
            teamView.getItems().setAll(obsTeamList);
        }

    }

    public void addPoint(){
        Team teamToAddPointsTo = (Team) teamView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        teamToAddPointsTo.setPoints(new SimpleIntegerProperty(1));
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        obsTeamList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ArrayList<>());
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        pointCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("points"));


    }
}
```

The model class:

```
package gameStats.model;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

/**
 * Created by lassebjorklund on 21/01/16.
 * For JuniorEvent_kampdata
 */
public class Team {

    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty points;

    public Team(SimpleStringProperty name, SimpleIntegerProperty points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.points = points;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points.get();
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty pointsProperty() {
        return this.points;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public void setPoints(SimpleIntegerProperty points) {
        this.points.add(points);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName() + " : " + getPoints();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to update points for the selected team in the table view. I want this to happen when i press a button that calls the "addPoint" method. But I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Hi @Lasse I suggest you change your title to something more descriptive,

Comment: Done, and thanks @Llewellyn1411

Comment: Without you telling us how you want to update the view (what the result should be and when it should happen), this will be pretty hard to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple problems with your code.

1. The type of the column should be the underlying data type, not the property type. For `SimpleStringProperty` use `TableColumn<Team, String>`. For `SimpleIntegerProperty` use `TableColumn<Team, Integer>` or `TableColumn<Team, Number>`.
2. the `setPoints` method should take an `int` or `Integer`, not `SimpleIntegerProperty`. It should be the same type the `getPoints` returns.
3. Inside `setPoints`, you should use `points.set`. `points.add` creates a new `NumberExpression` that represents the addition of the two properties, but doesn't change the actual property.

On the same note, it is probably a good idea to have the actual properties of `Team` as final fields, and only change their values. See [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) for more info.

Comment: [JavaFX 8 version of the tutorial linked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107) (though I think it may be exactly the same article), and (more helpfully) a [useful related powerpoint presentation](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/javafx-2-prog-model-1524061.pdf).